# Dynamic URL generation and SEO

Tags: seo, google, url, dynamic

We are integrating some web-services in our website and it is mostly about integrating post codes search within the website.

There are couple of ways to build this, the easiest is below but we are not sure what would be the impact of that on SEO

Client searches for a keyword on the page and we change the url of the website from www.sample.com/postcode/<> using javascript and the results corresponding to the search results get populated on the page.

If the client directly hits the same URL above, JS would parse the URL and load the same page with the same results. With this way we don't have to create pages manually for each post code search and we can just manipulate the DOM with the result from the API. We aren't sure if the page is same , google would index these pages or not or might index only half of it.

Other way of doing is that once the results are obtained from the API's we create the page dynamically for each and every search result which seems ugly.

Any pointers to this would be helpful. Thanks folks. Looking forward for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Well, google says they can effectively crawl and index dynamic URLs.

Static URLs are known to be better than dynamic URLs for a number of reasons including the following:

- Static URLs tend to rank better in search engines.
- The content found on dynamic pages is usually indexed by search
  engines much more slowly than that of static pages.
- Static URLs look friendlier to end users.

It's always advisable to use static content with static URLs as much as possible, but in cases where you decide to use dynamic content, you should give google the possibility to analyze your URL structure and not remove information by hiding parameters and making them look static.